# RMarkdown: Accordion the table of contents via CSS

Tags: css, r-markdown

I have a Rmarkdown document with a table of contents (TOC) on the left hand side.

The rmd file has a YAML header:

```
---
title: "Foo"
author: "Bar"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d-%B-%Y')`"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: bam.css
    theme: flatly
    toc: true
---
```

Here is bam.css in its entirety:

```
#TOC {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

#TOC::before {
  content: "";
}

body {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left:230px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Is there a simple way to modify this CSS so that the TOC will accordion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way of doing this is via `toc_float` in the YAML header. E.g.,:

```
 output: 
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
```